# Weeks and months between 2 dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have 2 Dates:

```
var Date1 = new Date(2013,01,01);
var Date2 = new Date(2014,05,06);
```

How could i get amount of weeks and months between this two dates ?

Comment: Maybe this can help you? https://github.com/mstum/TimeSpan.js

Comment: Or look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript